# How to add html class to above element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hope this title says what I want to do. I have a checkbox on my site. I want to check variable and then add `class='checked'` to above element. For example:

```
<div class="checker" id="uniform-personalData1"><span><input name="personalData1" id="personalData1" value="0" type="checkbox"></span></div>
```

If js variable like say `$a = 1` I want to add `class='checked'` to `<span>`. Like this:

```
<div class="checker" id="uniform-personalData1"><span class="checked"><input name="personalData1" id="personalData1" value="0" type="checkbox"></span></div>
```

How can I do this thing by using jquery ?

Kind regards

Comment: if ($a == 1) $("#uniform-personalData1 span").addClass("checked"); ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi @adam It's quite simple. Just use addClass method of jQuery. Like below.

```
    var $a = 1;
    if ($a === 1) {
      $('#uniform-personalData1 > span').addClass('checked');
      console.log($('#uniform-personalData1 span'));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for something like this, add a `change` event to `checkbox inputs` and get the value, if the value = 1 add class you want:

```js
$(":checkbox").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 1){
        $(this).closest("span").addClass("checked")
    }
    else $("span").removeClass("checked")
});
```

```css
.checked{
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checker" id="uniform-personalData1">
    <span>
      Value 0 : <input name="personalData1" id="personalData1" value="0" type="checkbox">
    </span><br>
    <span>
      Value 1 : <input name="personalData1" id="personalData1" value="1" type="checkbox">
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, reading your answer made me noticed that the title says "Above element" what I supose it's the label (though is not provided in the code, no label there).

I think you're right and he want's what you suggested. Nice understanding!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JQuery you must update the checkbox class to active when variable is set to 1 and remove it if it's 0 instead.

Wherever you change the variable value, you can do this:

```
if ($a == 1) {
    $("#personalData1").addClass("checked");
} else {
    $("#personalData1").removeClass("checked");
}
```

If you want to check the checkbox too you can use

```
$("#personalData1").prop("checked")
```

I suggest you to use a reactive framework like Angular, React or Vue. With this frameworks you can make the class be used checking a condition (such as the variable equals to 1) directly in the HTML template.

An angular example:

```
<input name="personalData1" id="personalData1" value="0" type="checkbox" [ngClass]="{'checked': $a == 1}"/>
```

Hope this helps you. Greetings.

Comment: I would not recommend him using a framework right now, due to his inability to code this in regular JS / JQuery. Would add a bit too much overhead for his skill level (probably). Good example for the future though

Comment: I agree, it's better not to start using a framework if you're not used to code in vanilla JS. But I like to provide full answers because it's public and maybe I can help other with my answer. 
But yes, better not start coding standard Javascript :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below Jquery script for check checkbox checked or not.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#personalData1').change(function(){
   if($("#personalData1").prop('checked') == true){
      $(this).parents('#uniform-personalData1').addClass('checked');
      console.log('checked');
    } else {
      $(this).parents('#uniform-personalData1').removeClass('checked');
      console.log('Unchecked');
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checker" id="uniform-personalData1">
  <span>
    <input name="personalData1" id="personalData1" type="checkbox" value="0">
  </span>
</div>
```